# Reliable way to detect ext2 or ext3 or ext4?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ext3, ext2

I need to detect a filesystem type from a C/C++ program using the filesystem superblock. However, I don't see much differences between superblocks for ext2 and ext4. The `s_rev_level` field is the same (=1), the `s_minor_rev_level` is the same (=0).

I could check some features from `s_feature_compat` (and other feature fields) and try to locate features, which aren't supported by ext2. But - the person, formatting a partition, could disable some features on purpose. So, this method can detect the ext4, but it can't distinguish between the ext2 and the ext4 with disabled ext4-specific features.

So, how to do that?

Comment: What is the difference between ext2 and ext4 if every difference has been disabled?

Comment: I checked the source code for `file` wondering what it does, but `file` currently reports an `ext4` filesystem with the journal turned off as `ext2`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - I see your point. But - a bunch of tools can do that, so I was wondering how they do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking at the code for various utilities and the kernel code for some time, it does seem that what [@Hauke suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123009/reliable-way-to-detect-ext2-or-ext3-or-ext4#comment194925_123009) is true - whether a filesystem is `ext2`/`ext3`/`ext4` is purely defined by the options that are enabled.

From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Features) on `ext4`:

> **Backward compatibility**
>
> ext4 is backward compatible with ext3 and ext2, making it possible to mount ext3 and ext2 as ext4. This will slightly improve performance, because certain new features of ext4 can also be used with ext3 and ext2, such as the new block allocation algorithm.
>
> ext3 is partially forward compatible with ext4. That is, ext4 can be mounted as ext3 (using "ext3" as the filesystem type when mounting). However, if the ext4 partition uses extents (a major new feature of ext4), then the ability to mount as ext3 is lost.

As most probably already know, there is similar compatibility between `ext2` and `ext3`.

After looking at the [code which `blkid` uses to distinguish different `ext` filesystems](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/libblkid/src/superblocks/ext.c), I was able to turn an `ext4` filesystem into something recognised as `ext3` (and from there to `ext2`). You should be able to repeat this with:

```
truncate -s 100M testfs
mkfs.ext4 -O ^64bit,^extent,^flex_bg testfs <<<y
blkid testfs
tune2fs -O ^huge_file,^dir_nlink,^extra_isize,^mmp testfs
e2fsck testfs
tune2fs -O metadata_csum testfs
tune2fs -O ^metadata_csum testfs
blkid testfs
./e2fsprogs/misc/tune2fs -O ^has_journal testfs
blkid testfs
```

First `blkid` output is:

```
testfs: UUID="78f4475b-060a-445c-a5d2-0f45688cc954" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext4"
```

Second is:

```
testfs: UUID="78f4475b-060a-445c-a5d2-0f45688cc954" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

And the final one:

```
testfs: UUID="78f4475b-060a-445c-a5d2-0f45688cc954" TYPE="ext2"
```

Note that I had to use a new version of `e2fsprogs` than was available in my distro to get the `metadata_csum` flag. The reason for setting, then clearing this was because I found no other way to affect the underlying `EXT4_FEATURE_RO_COMPAT_GDT_CSUM` flag. The underlying flag for `metadata_csum` (`EXT4_FEATURE_RO_COMPAT_METADATA_CSUM`) and `EXT4_FEATURE_RO_COMPAT_GDT_CSUM` are mutually exclusive. Setting `metadata_csum` disables `EXT4_FEATURE_RO_COMPAT_GDT_CSUM`, but un-setting `metadata_csum` does not re-enable the latter.

#### Conclusions

Lacking a deep knowledge of the filesystem internals, it seems either:

1. Journal checksumming is meant to be a defining feature of a filesystem created as `ext4` that you are really not supposed to disable and that fact that I have managed this is really a bug in `e2fsprogs`. Or,
2. All `ext4` features were always designed to be disabled and disabling them does make the filesystem to all intents an purposes an `ext3` filesystem.

Either way a high level of compatibility between the filesystems is clearly a design goal, compare this to ReiserFS and Reiser4 where Reiser4 is a complete redesign. What really matters is whether the features present are supported by the driver that is used to mount the system. As the Wikipedia article notes the `ext4` driver can be used with `ext3` and `ext2` as well (in fact there is a kernel option to always use the `ext4` driver and ditch the others). Disabling features just means that the earlier drivers will have no problems with the filesystem and so there are no reasons to stop them from mounting the filesystem.

#### Recommendations

To distinguish between the different `ext` filesystems in a C program, `libblkid` seems to be the best thing to use. It is part of `util-linux` and this is what the `mount` command uses to try to determine the filesystem type. API documentation is [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/libblkid-docs/).

If you have to do your own implementation of the check, then [testing the same flags as `libblkid`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/libblkid/src/superblocks/ext.c) seems to be the right way to go. Although notably the file linked has no mention of the `EXT4_FEATURE_RO_COMPAT_METADATA_CSUM` flag which appears to be tested in practice.

If you really wanted to go the whole hog, then looking at for journal checksums might be a surefire way of finding if a filesystem without these flags is (or perhaps *was*) `ext4`.

#### Update

It is actually somewhat easier to go in the opposite direction and promote an `ext2` filesystem to `ext4`:

```
truncate -s 100M test
mkfs.ext2 test
blkid test
tune2fs -O has_journal test
blkid test
tune2fs -O huge_file test
blkid test
```

The three `blkid` ouputs:

```
test: UUID="59dce6f5-96ed-4307-9b39-6da2ff73cb04" TYPE="ext2"
```

```
test: UUID="59dce6f5-96ed-4307-9b39-6da2ff73cb04" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

```
test: UUID="59dce6f5-96ed-4307-9b39-6da2ff73cb04" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext4"
```

The fact that `ext3`/`ext4` features can so easily by enabled on a filesystem that started out as `ext2` is probably the best demonstration that the filesystem type really is defined by the features.

Comment: AFAIK conclusion 2 is true: ext2/ext3/ext4 are drivers that share a significant part of their code. There are not three filesystem formats, but filesystem formats defined by a combination of features. A filesystem is ext4 if it uses a feature that isn't in the ext3 driver, and ext3 if it isn't ext4 but uses a feature that isn't in the ext2 driver.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but in looking at the output of `tune2fs -l ...` for each type of filesystem shows the following differences.

#### Filesystem features

*EXT2*

> Filesystem features:      ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype sparse_super

*EXT3*

> Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super

*EXT4*

> Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize

#### Journaling parameters

*EXT2*

Shows no parameter for journaling.

*EXT3*

Shows this:

```
Journal inode:            8
```

*EXT4*

Shows this:

```
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1967934
```