# Problem mounting GPT disk partition

Tags: partition, hard-disk, fdisk, gpt

I am trying to mount a partition on a GPT disk, but I get the following error:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 disk/
mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist
```

Looking at dmesg, I don't see any errors on /dev/sda:

```
$ dmesg | grep sda
[    1.367508] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[    1.367514] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.367607] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.367611] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.367654] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.367936]  sda:
[    1.392417] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

fdisk reports the GPT partition:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 363376 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16128 * 512 = 8257536 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1       45423   366283322+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

parted fails:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
```

Kernel seems to have support for EFI ([How to mount a partition on a disk that has an EFI GPT partition table in Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.3 (Lenny)](http://www.pjc.me.uk/efi-gpt/))

```
$ cat /boot/config-2.6.32-5-amd64 | grep EFI
CONFIG_EFI=y
CONFIG_FB_EFI=y
CONFIG_EFI_VARS=m
CONFIG_CACHEFILES=m
# CONFIG_CACHEFILES_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_CACHEFILES_HISTOGRAM is not set
CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION=y
```

How can I mount this GPT partition?

EDIT: I've just attached the same disk that is failing to another machine and I can see the contents without a hitch. Putting it back to the original box, I am having the same issue.

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem as you - did you ever solve it?

Comment: I thought I had this problem, but turned out I was trying to mount /dev/sda rather than /dev/sda1. Worked without a hitch (even with a large GPT disc) once I switched that.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use `fdisk` to work with GPT disks, it will only work with MBR disks. Any disk that > 2TB must be GPT.

You likely cannot mount this HDD because even though the kernel has detected it (in the `dmesg` output) the HDD hasn't been partitioned or formatted with a filesystem so that it can be mounted.

Try the following to do this:

```
$ sudo sfdisk -l
```

This will list all the GPT devices & partitions. You can create a partition using `sfdisk` as well.

```
$ sudo sfdisk /dev/sda
```

After you've created a partition using `sfdisk` you'll want to format it:

```
$ mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
```

With the above done you should then be able to mount the HDD as you were originally attempting.

#### Determining a HDD's filesystem

If you're unsure how a HDD and/or partition may have been formatted you can use the command `dumpe2fs` to accomplish this.

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | less
```

Parsing the output from this command is covered in this U&L Q&A titled: [Reliable way to detect ext2 or ext3 or ext4?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123009/reliable-way-to-detect-ext2-or-ext3-or-ext4/123025#123025)

#### References

- [Linux: what is on each of my hard drives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114185/linux-what-is-on-each-of-my-hard-drives/114204#114204)
- [Linux/GParted can see partition table but dd bs=512 count=1 can't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75530/linux-gparted-can-see-partition-table-but-dd-bs-512-count-1-cant/75545#75545)

Comment: Thanks, the troubling thing is: This is not a new disk, I have been using it for almost a year and I'm  absolutely certain that there is (or was) an ext4 volume in there.

Comment: @Hamza - the lack of a `/dev/sda1` in `dmesg` means the kernel is not auto detecting any useful filesystem on it. Do you have other EXT4 devices mounted? That would confirm that the drivers are available/working so that EXT4 devices can be mounted.

Comment: Yes, there are four other disks with a number of ext4 partitions mounted on the same machine.

Comment: @Hamza - output of `sfdisk -l`?

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 364801 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
  Warning: The partition table looks like it was made
    for C/H/S=*/256/63 (instead of 364801/255/63).
  For this listing I'll assume that geometry.
Units = cylinders of 8257536 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1          0+  45422-  45423- 366283322+  ee  GPT
/dev/sda2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty

Comment: Sorry about formatting.

Comment: I've just attached the same disk that is failing to another machine and I can see the contents without a hitch. This keeps getting stranger :)

Comment: @Hamza - try using `mount --verbose ...` for additional info on why it's unsuccessful. Also `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sda1` are showing up as device labels on the misbehaving box? Please confirm this, assuming they are given your `fdisk` output but just want to check it off the list.

Comment: They do show up as device labels, the output of `mount --verbose` is still: mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist

Comment: @Hamza - can you try getting the output of `strace mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 disk/`? Please attach this to your Q or use http://pastebin.com/ and include the URL here.

Answer (score 3):

Forget about `fdisk`, use `parted -l` or `gdisk -l` (from package `gptfdisk`) instead ...

Comment: Welcome to *nix.SE! One-line opinion-based answers like this are often not too helpful. Please consider explaning why these other options might be better; using links and documentation as references will further benefit the quality of your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Having had exactly the same issue as you, by solution was to use a different SATA controller. The problem occurred when the drive in question was connected via a USB SATA controller. In order to access the drive I unplugged the DVD drive from the motherboard onboard SATA controller (I have no spare sockets) and plugged the drive in (no reboot required - SATA is hot pluggable).